# PIXI RenderTexture "use RenderTexture.create instead of the ctor directly" warning

Tags: canvas, sprite, pixi.js, render-to-texture

In PIXI.js I am creating texture from custom graphics to be used as a sprite (so I can add interactivity to it. The code looks as follows:

```
function makeTextureFromGraphics(props) {
  const gfx = new PIXI.Graphics()
  gfx.beginFill(props.fill)
  /* ...make my graphics here... */
  gfx.endFill()

  const texture = new PIXI.RenderTexture(app.renderer, props.size , props.size)
  texture.render(gfx)
  return texture
}
```

Then I create a texture with customized props and create sprite:

```
const myTexture = makeTextureFromGraphics(myprops)
const sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(myTexture)
sprite.on('pointerup', pointerUpCallback)
```

Then I am adding the sprite to app like so:

```
app.stage.addChild(sprite)
```

With such setup I get warning:

`Please use RenderTexture.create(10, 10) instead of the ctor directly.`

Can you please give some hint how to refactor code so it's inline with RenderTexture.create?

In [docs](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/core_textures_RenderTexture.js.html) I've found example:

```
let renderTexture = PIXI.RenderTexture.create(800, 600);
let sprite = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("spinObj_01.png");
renderer.render(sprite, renderTexture);
```

but it renders sprite from image not from graphics, moreover renderTexture has no reference to my graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the example, that generates texture from graphics without warnings

```
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.beginFill(0xff22aa);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
graphics.endFill();

var texture = app.renderer.generateTexture(graphics);

var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
app.stage.addChild(sprite);
```

https://repl.it/@CurlyBrace/PixiTexture